# quarkus Multi<String> not quoting strings

Tags: java, quarkus, mutiny

Background: I'm just getting started with Quarkus and am going through https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive

I have the following endpoint defined:

```java
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/greeting/{name}/{count}/{delayInSeconds}")
    public Multi<String> greetings(String name, long count, short delayInSeconds) {
        return service.greetings(name, delayInSeconds, count);
    }
```

The details of the underlying `service` aren't particularly relevant I don't think; it produces a stream of `"hello {name} - {idx}"`.

What I'm seeing in the returned http response is unquoted strings (invalid json):

```
curl http://localhost:8080/hello/greeting/neo/4/1

[hello neo - 0,hello neo - 1,hello neo - 2,hello neo - 3]
```

I tried replacing the `pom.xml` dependency of `quarkus-resteasy-reactive` to `quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson` but to the same effect (I believe because `String` is already registered here: https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#resource-types ).

Is there a safe means of doing this? Or is the idea to just convert the `Multi` to a `List` so that it can be serialized properly by jackson?

I'll note the example given at https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-reactive (official docs) shows a quoted response:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/hello/greeting/3/neo
["hello neo - 0", "hello neo - 1", "hello neo - 2"]
```

---

**Update**

This effectively accomplishes what I want though I want to confirm it's not blocking an i/o thread:

```java
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/greeting/{name}/{count}/{delayInSeconds}")
    // NOTE: conversion to `Uni<List` from `Multi`
    public Uni<List<String>> greetings(String name, long count, short delayInSeconds) {
        return service.greetings(name, delayInSeconds, count).collect().asList();
    }
```

---

**Update**

As noted in the comments, this is an open bug: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/18043
Closing.

Comment: There is an open issue for this: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/18043 which will likely be fixed soon

Comment: Gah, must have missed that. Thanks @geoand .

Comment: No problem, we will hopefully fix it soon for a `2.0.x` release

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, this is an open bug: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/18043 Closing.